# What is the difference between the principal square root of $x$ and $x^{1/2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Today I learned that the square root symbol ($\sqrt{}$) represents only the "principal" square root of a number. What about exponents?—if I write $x^{1/2}$, would that encompass the negative square root of $x$ as well?

Edit: $x$ is a non-negative real number.

Comment: No. $x^{1/2}$ is a function, so it has only one value for a fixed argument.

Comment: In Real Analysis, by arbitrary convention, for $x \geq 0, ~x^{(1/2)}~$ is synonymous with the *principal square root* of $x$.  This is because absent *some* convention around the interpretation of $~x^{(1/2)},~$ the expression would be ambiguous, for $x > 0.$

Comment: I take it we are assuming here that $x$ is a nonnegative real number. Otherwise, all bets are off.

Comment: For *nonnegative* $x,$ in *real* analysis, $\sqrt[n]x$ and $x^{\frac1n}$ have the same meaning: the principal $n$th root of $x.$

Comment: @user2661923 That makes sense. Is there an authoritative source, like a textbook, I can get this from?

Comment: @unloadedmaterial Not that I know of.  My guess is that someone probably wrote it in a book somewhere, but I have never seen it.  My comment is simply an inference that ambiguity must be avoided.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke It does not "have" to be a function though, does it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes; I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @ryang Thank you.

Comment: Answering on PrzemysławScherwentke's behalf: in real analysis, $x^{\frac1n}$ is essentially a function, whereas in complex analysis, I like to treat $x^{\frac1n}$ as having multiple values and use $\sqrt[n]x$ either only for nonnegative $x$ or with the branch cut specified.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of "square root" is that it inverts the process of squaring (more generally: $n$th roots invert exponentiation). It is what subtraction is to addition and what division is to multiplication. Exponentiation has another inverse, the logarithm, because it is not a commutative operation, but that's another matter.

If we want to invert squaring, we run into trouble, because we cannot: the function is not [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). $2^2=4$, but also $(-2)^2=4$, so there is no way of retrieving $2$ or $-2$ from $4$ without further information.

This is unlike adding a number, easily reversed, or multiplying a number—reversible if and only if that number is not $0$ (hence, we can't divide by $0$).

Square roots are well behaved: from either square root, $x$, the other square root is $-x$. Thus, we define notation to give a "principal" value, the one that is useful in the most contexts, and it's not hard to find the other value if both are needed (or just the negative one).

Both $\sqrt{x}$ and $x^{1/2}$ are notations to describe the *principal* square root of $x$. The best notation for the *other* square root is $-\sqrt{x}$. Example notations that encompass both roots: $\pm \sqrt{x}$ or $\{\sqrt{x},-\sqrt{x}\}$.

As commenters have said, conventions may differ in a context such as complex analysis where it may be important to distinguish between functions (one input, one output) and multifunctions (one input, multiple outputs). It is not universal that, for instance, $x^{1/n}$ is the multifunction and $\sqrt[n]x$ is the function, but some authors may specify this convention and then use it throughout their writing.

If you like, you can use $\sqrt{x}$ to refer to both square roots, but this isn't standard so you need to make it clear before you first use it. Notice that it is then no longer an expression, so values like $\sqrt{4}+1$ also need explaining: does this mean *both* $-1$ *and* $3$?